# The gitache-populate step of cmake configure gives the error: fatal: ambiguous argument 'stable': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: configuration

While configuring a project that uses aicxx and [gitache](https://github.com/CarloWood/gitache), I get the following error:

```
...
[ 11%] Performing update step for 'gitache-populate'
cd /home/carlo/projects/aicxx/linuxviewer/linuxviewer-objdir/_deps/gitache-src && /usr/bin/cmake -P /home/carlo/projects/aicxx/linuxviewer/linuxviewer-objdir/_deps/gitache-subbuild/gitache-populate-prefix/tmp/gitache-populate-gitupdate.cmake
fatal: ambiguous argument 'stable': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
From https://github.com/CarloWood/gitache
   bef7d0d..5c68f7b  stable     -> origin/stable
CMake Error at /home/carlo/projects/aicxx/linuxviewer/linuxviewer-objdir/_deps/gitache-subbuild/gitache-populate-prefix/tmp/gitache-populate-gitupdate.cmake:121 (message):
....
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is probably that you just pulled a `CMakeLists.txt` change
that switched from using one gitache branch to another (from `master` to `stable` [in this case](https://github.com/CarloWood/linuxviewer/commit/711fcca603ed69f5665a48198b6368a6550b857e)).

The easiest way to recover is to entirely clean the project and configure from scratch.

For example, remove the cmake build directoy:

```
rm -rf /home/carlo/projects/aicxx/linuxviewer/linuxviewer-objdir
```

Then rerun ./autogen.sh and configure and build as usual.
Technically running `autogen.sh` is only necessary after running `make maintainer-clean`, if the project supports that (normally cmake doesn't, so it would have to be manually added by the project), but it never hurts.